Understanding why Condition keeps turning false
I am new to Pinescript and trying to code an indicator.
If following condition is met
OPSCond :=  barstate.isconfirmed and close > low[1] and low < low[1] and  close > low 

Make the variable isOPS true
isOPS :=  OPSCond ? true : false

Assign the OPS parameters ie OPS value, OPSIndex (bar index) and OPSTime (when isOPS is true)
OPS      :=  isOPS   ? low[1]        : nz(OPS[1])
OPSIndex :=  isOPS   ? bar_index[1]  : nz(OPSIndex[1])
OPSTime  :=  isOPS   ? timeline()    : nz(OPSTime[1])

This seems to be working fine as lines are drawn correctly.
The code written to check when the condition become invalid also seems to work fine. Not repeating it here.
However the isOPS value is shown as false on every bar even when it should be true. See the attached picture.
I need the script to have isOPS as true when the chart is showing OPS Line (Green Line) correctly at the OPS level so that  can develop the script further.
I have tried many things but nothing seems to work. Where am I going wrong and what can I do to correct it?
Full script:
//@version=5
indicator("OPS only",max_bars_back = 500, overlay = true)

//Function region
    
timeline()=>
    txt1 = str.tostring(year(time),"#")
    txt2 = month(time)>9?str.tostring(month(time),"#"):"0"+ str.tostring(month(time),"#")
    txt3 = dayofmonth(time)>9?str.tostring(dayofmonth(time),"#"):"0"+ str.tostring(dayofmonth(time),"#")
    txt4 = str.tostring(hour(time)*100+minute(time),"#")
    timeline1 = txt1 + txt2 + txt3 + txt4
    timeline = math.round(str.tonumber(timeline1))
//Input Region
var color ColorOPS      =   #08803a
var bool long   =   true

//Input Region Ends

// Variable Declarations


var bool OPSCond    =   false, OPSCond := na(OPSCond[1])
var bool isOPS      =   false, isOPS :=nz(isOPS[1])
var OPSLine         =   line.new(na,na,na,na,color=ColorOPS,style = line.style_solid,width=2)
var float OPS       =   na, OPS := nz(OPS[1])
var label OPSLabel  =   label.new(na,na,text = "",xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.belowbar,color=color.new(color.black,100),textcolor = ColorOPS)
var int OPSIndex    =   na, OPSIndex := nz(OPSIndex[1])
var int OPSTime     =   na, OPSTime := nz(OPSTime[1])

//OPS Region Starts

OPSCond             :=  barstate.isconfirmed and close > low[1] and low < low[1] and  close > low 
isOPS               :=  OPSCond ? true                              : false
OPS                 :=  isOPS   ? low[1]                            : nz(OPS[1])
OPSIndex            :=  isOPS   ? bar_index[1]                      : nz(OPSIndex[1])
OPSTime             :=  isOPS   ? timeline()    : nz(OPSTime[1])

// If any bar closes below OPS level then invalidate OPS
if barstate.isconfirmed and close < OPS
    isOPS       :=  false
    OPS         :=  na
    OPSIndex    :=  na
    OPSTime     :=  na

    line.set_xy1(OPSLine,na,na)
    line.set_xy2(OPSLine,na,na)    
    // Delete OPSLabel  - inserted on 18.10.23
    
    label.set_xy(OPSLabel,na,na)
    label.set_text(OPSLabel,na)

    // Redraw OPSLine
if isOPS
    line.set_xy1(long?OPSLine:na,OPSIndex,OPS)
    line.set_xy2(long?OPSLine:na,OPSIndex+5,OPS)    
    // Redraw OPSLabel  - inserted on 18.10.23
    
    txt = "OPS\n" + str.tostring(OPS,"0.00")
    label.set_xy(long?OPSLabel:na,OPSIndex,OPS-5)
    label.set_text(long?OPSLabel:na,txt)
    
plotshape(isOPS,title="OPS",style = shape.arrowup,location=location.belowbar)   
//OPS Region ends
    
// All Data Table Printing for debugging

var table AllTable = table.new(position.top_right, 2, 23, bgcolor=color.white, frame_color=color.white, frame_width=2, border_width=2)
//Initialise the table
txt000 = isOPS?"isOPS:True":not(isOPS)?"isOPS:false":"na"
table.cell(AllTable, 0, 0, text=txt000, bgcolor=color.silver, text_color=color.navy, text_size=size.small)
txt001 = "OPS:" + str.tostring(OPS,'#')
table.cell(AllTable, 0, 1, text=txt001, bgcolor=color.silver, text_color=color.navy, text_size=size.small)
txt002 = "OPSIndex:" + str.tostring(OPSIndex,'#')
table.cell(AllTable, 0, 2, text=txt002, bgcolor=color.silver, text_color=color.navy, text_size=size.small)
txt003 = "OPSt:" + str.tostring(OPSTime,'#')
table.cell(AllTable, 0, 3, text=txt003, bgcolor=color.silver, text_color=color.navy, text_size=size.small)


Example Chart

In response to Gustavo's comment I am adding 2 pics that show what I am trying to say.
isOPS = false

isOPS plotted correctly but its value is shown as false in table


you say isOPS value is shown as false on every bar even when it should be true but isOPS is true in every arrow plot.

You are correct. The arrow plot is showing correctly on every bar where isOPS is true. But then isOPS becomes false immediately.  When I do bar-by-bar replay , then in the table, on every bar isOPS is shown as false.  This is where I am getting lost.

Found the solution. Modified Code below.
//@version=5
indicator("OPS only",max_bars_back = 500, overlay = true)

//Function region
    
timeline()=>
    txt1 = str.tostring(year(time),"#")
    txt2 = month(time)>9?str.tostring(month(time),"#"):"0"+ str.tostring(month(time),"#")
    txt3 = dayofmonth(time)>9?str.tostring(dayofmonth(time),"#"):"0"+ str.tostring(dayofmonth(time),"#")
    txt4 = str.tostring(hour(time)*100+minute(time),"#")
    timeline1 = txt1 + txt2 + txt3 + txt4
    timeline = math.round(str.tonumber(timeline1))
//Input Region
var color ColorOPS      =   #08803a
var bool long   =   true

//Input Region Ends

// Variable Declarations


var bool OPSCond    =   false, OPSCond := na(OPSCond[1])
var bool isOPS      =   false, isOPS :=nz(isOPS[1])
var line OPSLine         =   line.new(na,na,na,na,color=ColorOPS,style = line.style_solid,width=2)
var float OPS       =   na, OPS := nz(OPS[1])
var label OPSLabel  =   label.new(na,na,text = "",xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.belowbar,color=color.new(color.black,100),textcolor = ColorOPS)
var int OPSIndex    =   na, OPSIndex := nz(OPSIndex[1])
var int OPSTime   =   na, OPSTime := nz(OPSTime[1])
var bool OPSFresh = false 
var int OPSCount = 0 // Counts No of OPS Formed. Is reset to 0 when an OPS is ivalidated. If is  greater than 0 new OPS is not alllowed.
var bool OPSCondFirst    =   false, OPSCondFirst := na(OPSCondFirst[1])
var bool isOPSFirst      =   false, isOPSFirst :=nz(isOPSFirst[1])
var float OPSFirst       =   na, OPSFirst := nz(OPSFirst[1])
var int OPSIndexFirst    =   na, OPSIndexFirst := nz(OPSIndexFirst[1])
var int OPSTimeFirst   =   na, OPSTimeFirst := nz(OPSTimeFirst[1])
var bool OPSFreshFirst = false 
//New Session
newDay = bool(ta.change(dayofweek))
if newDay
    OPSCond    :=   false
    isOPS      :=   false
    OPSLine         :=   line.new(na,na,na,na,color=ColorOPS,style = line.style_solid,width=2)
    OPS       :=   na
    OPSLabel  :=   label.new(na,na,text = "",xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.belowbar,color=color.new(color.black,100),textcolor = ColorOPS)
    OPSIndex    :=   na
    OPSTime   :=   na
    OPSFresh := false  
    OPSCount := 0
    alert("First bar", freq = alert.freq_all)
//OPS Region Starts
if OPSCount == 0
    isOPS           :=  barstate.isconfirmed and close > low[1] and low < low[1] and  close > low // and not(low>OPS) //and not(close>OPS[1])
    if isOPS
        OPS                 :=  low[1]
        OPSCount            :=  OPSCount + 1
        OPSIndex            :=  bar_index[1]
        OPSTime             :=  timeline()

// If any bar closes below OPS level then OPS invalidated
if barstate.isconfirmed and close < OPS
    isOPS       :=  false
    OPS         :=  na
    OPSIndex    :=  na
    OPSTime     :=  na
    OPSCount    := 0
    line.set_xy1(OPSLine,na,na)
    line.set_xy2(OPSLine,na,na)    
    // Delete OPSLabel  - inserted on 18.10.23
    
    label.set_xy(OPSLabel,na,na)
    label.set_text(OPSLabel,na)

    // Redraw OPSLine

if isOPS
    line.set_xy1(long?OPSLine:na,OPSIndex,OPS)
    line.set_xy2(long?OPSLine:na,OPSIndex+5,OPS)    
    // Redraw OPSLabel  - inserted on 18.10.23
    
    txt = "OPS\n" + str.tostring(OPS,"0.00")
    label.set_xy(long?OPSLabel:na,OPSIndex,OPS-5)
    label.set_text(long?OPSLabel:na,txt)
    
 
plotshape(isOPS and ta.change(OPSCount)==1,title="OPS",style = shape.arrowup,location=location.belowbar)    
//OPS Region ends

